# Problema vídeo en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, menú, video

La dificultad que tengo es que el vídeo me sale cortado, y no se ajusta de manera responsive, es un vídeo que ocupa el grande de la pantalla, y hay mismo tiene el menú hamburguesa, pero sale cortado.

No sé por qué sucede.

```css
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
        <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
 
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Lim </span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Products</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Services</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Portfolios</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Achievements</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Blog</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div>

 <video class="video"src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" autoplay loop/>



    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que versión de Boostrap estas utilizando?

Comment: Hola, =) la versión es Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes colocar una etiqueta al rededor de tu `<video>` como te muestro a continuación, Este ejemplo es valido para `<iframe>`, `<embed>`, `<video>`, y `<object>`

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
<!-- 21:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 1:1 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

**Fuente:** [Boostrap Docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/) (Lamentablemente en Ingles)